# Better accuracy function in a hard to predict Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

So in summary my input is an array and output values are in range [-1, 1]. Currently, my loss is always about *0.1* and accuracy is about *0.05*. So my question is **How do I make the model care more about getting closer to the correct prediction and not about how to predict the exact float value?** (I would like to see accuracy be something like 80% not some low value because it didn't (and probably can't) predict the exact float value)

Comment: what's your loss function? If it's something standard like squared error loss/L2 loss then it already "cares about getting closer".

Comment: I would suggest you either transform it into a classification problem by discretizing your target range [-1, 1] into classes e.g. [-1, -0.9], [-0.9, -0.8], ..., or, better yet, use a more adequate loss function, e.g. one that is 0 in case of deviations of the predicted value from the true value smaller than a desired threshold (in absolute values) and then (linearly) increasing for larger deviations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelHodel That's one option but unfortunately the dataset is very unbalanced - most of the values are close to 0 (also dividing it into some equal segments is not an option because I have multiple datasets (due to a lot of data and not a lot of RAM). Also to be clear I am using **mean_squared_error** as a loss function. Thanks to OliverDain now the problem is **how to get the accuracy metric to display the closeness to the answer not how often did it accurately predict the exact float value.**

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The fact that you were using a metric used for classification problems (i.e. accuracy) in a regression setting was just a bit confusing.